# php code is not parsing properly in HTML input tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

I have scrpit that reads from the database.And it displays properly in the other textboxes, except for one textbox which is supposed to display the value of a students test 1.
the logic is->if the value is >0 then that text box must be disabled.

Here is the code that does not display properly on the text box. What Am I missing?

```
<td>Test 1</td>
<td><input class="form-control" disabled placeholder="Enter Test 1" id="test1" name="test_1" type="text" value="
<?php 
echo $test1;
if($test1>0){
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("test1").disabled = true;
</script>
<?php
}
?>"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert a script tag in the value of an input? If so, you cannot do that.

Comment: Why you put javascript inside `value` attribute?

Comment: You can't add script to the value attrib of an input tag. Also, PHP executes on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: I want to disable that textbox if the result on from the db is a value greater than zero, so I tried the above method to try to dynamically disable the textbox if the value is greater than zero. If there is a better way of doing it, I would highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
<td>
    <input 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter Test 1" 
        id="test1" 
        name="test_1" 
        type="text" 
        value="<?php echo $test1;?>" 
        <?php if ($test1 > 0) echo ' disabled';?>
    >
</td>
```

Comment: thanks it is working very well.I really appreciate your assistance.Thanks a lot @u_mulder